# MTLRenderCommandEncoder for compute processing?

Tags: ios, metal

Trying to put together a puzzle:

- Is it OK to use [MTLRenderCommandEncoder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlrendercommandencoder) not for rendering but for computing tasks?
- If not, does it possible to do vertex shader job using [MTLComputeCommandEncoder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlcomputecommandencoder)?

Use case:

- Apply simultaneously 2x zoom effect & shake effect (with 10% of width offset) to the stored video file.

Comment: iOS and tvOS [restrict](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/gpu_devices_and_work_submission/preparing_your_metal_app_to_run_in_the_background?language=objc) a background app’s access to the GPU, to guarantee foreground app performance.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Let me replace `background processing` with `compute processing` for the sub-case when we are still in foreground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can process buffers (including vertex buffers) in compute shaders. There are tons of techniques that are using it: [particle systems](https://ubm-twvideo01.s3.amazonaws.com/o1/vault/GDC2014/Presentations/Gareth_Thomas_Compute-based_GPU_Particle.pdf), [custom tessellation](https://advances.realtimerendering.com/s2022/index.html#_Bisection_Based_Triangulation) from Unity in SIGGRAPH'22, [cloth simulation](https://ubm-twvideo01.s3.amazonaws.com/o1/vault/gdc2015/presentations/Vaisse_Alexis_Ubisoft%20Cloth%20Simulation.pdf) and many others.

In addition to compute shaders in OpenGL there is [transform feedback](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Transform_Feedback) that allows you to use part of rendering pipeline (before rasterization). However, Metal does not provide API for it.